# Completely disable windows defender notifications windows 8 and 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, windows-defender

We have some screens showing information to visitors (for some products) in front of production lines, these computers are not even connected to the internet nor have user access at all, but the message that says windows defender signatures are really old may give the wrong message to a visitors or possible clients like "they don't even enforce security on their PCs", how can I completely disable either the  windows defender notifications or windows defender completely?

The only notifications that I can disable are the not critical ones, and the outdated definitions are considered critical. :/

Not the same as the suggested repeated question:
when you disable windows defender SECURITY CENTER starts to gripe about no antivirus protection with the same notifications I want to disable (even more now).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Windows Defender in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/947873/disable-windows-defender-in-windows-10)

Comment: not the same, when you disable windows defender SECURITY CENTER starts to gripe about no antivirus protection with the same notifications I want to disable (even more now)

Comment: Have you been through the steps here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/configure-notifications-windows-defender-antivirus

Comment: If you install any AV product it will effectively disable Windows Defender (unless you reenable it).  Another product might offer you more customizability on notifications.

Comment: I don't want another product as these devices are not even connected to the net and are not accesible by any user (no usbs, cds, etc).

Comment: You might be unable to disable the notifications you want to disable so I am suggesting a solution

Comment: Thank you, but Installing more apps that we dont actually need and will serve no other purpose apart from hiding the notifications seems overkill to me, also would need to keep that new AC updated and properly licensed (company policies, If i go that route) , and with no internet it will be a monthly pain, I ended up completely disabling security center using local security policies, a little too much also, but at least will not have to add more software and work for a dumb display.