# How to disable Windows 10 defender service (W10 1909)

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

On Windows 10 1909 enterprise, I have a process "Antimalware Service executable", within which the service: "Windows defender antivirus service"; which takes 115BM of memory.

However, in group policy, "Windows defender antivirus" I have "Turn off Windows defender antivirus" enabled, which help says:

> This policy setting turns off Windows Defender Antivirus.
>
> If you enable this policy setting, Windows Defender Antivirus does not run, and will not scan computers for malware or other potentially
>   unwanted software.

As well as "Turn off real-time protection" enabled (but this should not change a thing since the sus-mentionned parameter was turned off).

If I remember well the process was not running in 1809 with this policy. How can I in the end disable the process ? Is this a bug ?

Comment: A decent, name brand anti virus will turn off Windows Defender to allow Defender to co-exist with the third party AV.  Otherwise Windows Defender should be allowed to run.

Comment: @John I'm not looking for a workaround. Group policy is used to and is supposed to work (switch off AV).

Comment: Windows Defender will keep itself ON unless another AV takes its place. That is what we see here on our machines.

Comment: @John Your statement contradicts Windows' group policy help and my previous observations. Do you have any reference to your claim ?

Comment: Try setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\DisableAntiSpyware  = 1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Windows Defender in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/947873/disable-windows-defender-in-windows-10)

Comment: The "DisableAntiSpyware" key is part of one of the solutions, but if I add it, it is removed by Windows (the dword is deleted), and the AV is still running.

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot: it seems to depend whether your run on real hardware or a VM. Apparently MS will let you turn off the AV on a VM but not on bare metal even in 1**8**09 with recent iterations of their AV https://superuser.com/questions/1575029/windows-defender-re-enables-itself-by-deleting-disableantispyware-key-on-real-ha All of this poorly documented as it's usual for MS. https://youtu.be/qbKGw8MQ0i8?t=1610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct action is to disable the `Tamper protection` in `Windows security`/`virus&threat protection settings`. Even without the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\DisableAntiSpyware = 1` the group policy `Turn off Windows defender antivirus` to `enabled` will have effect.

Registry keys should be used as last option.

Comment: Yeah MS documents that. But that doesn't seem always work. https://superuser.com/questions/1575029/windows-defender-re-enables-itself-by-deleting-disableantispyware-key-on-real-ha

Answer (score 1):

Another method. Go to Settings, Security, Virus & threat protection, Manage
settings, Tamper protection. Set to Off. Then add this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection]
"DisableRealtimeMonitoring"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh windows installation make sure you do all the windows updates. For some reason windows wont always find all the needed/recent updates for your device right away so let your PC on for a day or two, restart every 5-6 hours and check for windows updates during these two days. After these two days, make sure every device in device manager is working properly (no unknown devices or yellow triangles under devices), so either install windows optional updates (which should install the appropriate drivers), or download the drivers for your device yourself.

At the last day of the updates, use window's cleaner to clean the window's updates cache:
[image: windows update cache]
restart, and check for updates one last time.

After these are done:

Disable tamper protection in windows defender and then use:

[winaerotweaker](https://winaerotweaker.com/) to disable windows update (and other crap) and restart,
[IObit Unlocker](https://superuser.com/questions/1824564/iobit-unlocker-how-does-it-work-how-to-delete-system-files-on-windows) or [Unlocker](https://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) to remove Antimalware Service Executable folder and file from your hard drive.

Additionally:

[WPD.exe](https://wpd.app/) to disable telemetry and restart,
[OOSU10.exe](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) to disable whatever is left and restart.

[Win-Debloat-Tools](https://github.com/LeDragoX/Win-Debloat-Tools) to debloat your system (they have some in-depth tweaks) and restart.

Finally, its useful to follow a video as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIftrmT-PmM) as every year, new people find new ways to debloat windows.

Remember that after a windows update, some of the disabled features might get re-installed/re-enabled. Make sure you have automatic windows updates turned off (check for windows updates when you want to check) and every now and then check the window's features configuration (if they got re-enabled).

I have achieved less than 2.5 GB ram usage with the above tools.

For daily use I recommend using [BCuninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com/) to uninstall files (its a deep uninstaller but open-source) in combination with [everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) which is a tool that can search everything in your PC, to delete leftovers from uninstalled programs (as BCuninstaller can't find everything).

Tools like [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/) are good for registry cleaning and important: startup programs disabling. Disabling program's auto-update features and just enabling them once every 3-4 months just for the updates to happen, is a great way to save some GBs of ram. There are some startup stuff you might disable from CCleaner and ruin your day, like you can disable the Wifi completely, the printer capability and the audio of windows. They are reversible, just find out which service was the one for audio/wifi/printer and re-enable it.

After doing all of the above, you might want to do something to reduce latency (includes unlocking all cores of your CPU, using a debloater for your Nvidia drivers etc.), I recommend [this](https://youtu.be/sbXzM60ad8I?si=sCdYpKZ8VfT6gGkB) video.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. You can use [**Defender Remover / Defender Disabler**](https://github.com/ionuttbara/windows-defender-remover) tool.

[image]

Or **[privacy.sexy](https://privacy.sexy/)** script. Type in 'defender' in search and there are various scripts available to disable various functions of Microsoft Defender.

[image]

However, I do not suggest checking **Microsoft Defender firewall** since it will eventually cause issues with your system when you try to use Windows installer (msi files) for example and it won't be able to add firewall rules and installer process might fail with "Setup Wizard ended prematurely" type of errors.