# Disable Win10 security (Defender, Antivirus, whatever)

Tags: windows-10, security, windows-defender

I had problems with Windows 10 since very first day. Horrible OS, but my new PC can support only this (no Win7 sadly). Now I'm having a new problem, as well as many other people - Windows keep on deleting my files! It says something about virus and just removes it without asking. I tried everything I found on internet - settings, registry, services, local group policy - nothing. Is there a way to just disable every possible kind of security in Win10? Just stop everything? I'll take the risk, I just want it to stop...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Windows Defender in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/947873/disable-windows-defender-in-windows-10)

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that Defender is making the correct call & ignoring/bypassing it is not going to go well for you?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can block this annoying "antivirus" by third-party tools (don't worry, they totally clean and only do their purpose).

I think the first at all is this tool - [Defender Control](https://www.sordum.org/9480/defender-control-v1-6/) from sordum (very known bright developer). in this tool you can simple and fast click to stop the defender, and by click you can turn it back on again.

this is direct link for the program: https://www.sordum.org/files/downloads.php?st-defender-control

good luck and use it carefully.

Comment: YES! Thak you. Finally...

Comment: happy to help.. curiosting thing - why my answer get only downvoting, if this is the **correct** answer.. no matter

Answer (score 1):

You should perhaps think in a different direction. Windows 10 Defender works very well, uses very little resource, and does not get in the way.

Open Windows Defender (System Tray, may be a hidden icon). On the first screen make sure all functions are green and there are no security errors. Now go to the Threat Protection settings and go Manage Settings and set and change as suits you.

Use the Allowed Threat Settings to allow some files you might have to be excluded from scanning.  Take care with this setting.

Windows Defender is top rated, and if you wish not to use it, you need a top rated (probably paid) A/V and Firewall security app.

I appreciate you are apparently new to Windows 10, but it works very well - I have had it running in production for 5 years now.

Three things:

1. Updates:  They WILL happen. Go to Windows Updates and set Active Hours so restarts happen in OFF hours.
2. Security:  Is enforced.  Work with the Security settings to help and not to hinder.
3. Take some time to learn the settings. 95% or more of what you need to set is in Windows Settings. Go through each screen and learn where the settings are. Big change from prior with everything in Control Panel. The registry is NOT a solution to this at all.

Good luck and post specific questions if you have issues.

Comment: he ask for stop this service. yes he know all the "risks".
in his words: "I'll take the risk, I just want it to stop..."