# Can't disable Windows Defender

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I need to disable windows defend but I'm not able. I think i messed up in the regedit section in the past and now all the settings can't be changed.

I tried deleting the files i added in regedit but didn't work, tried to change the value but didn't work either.

[If i click on dismiss it will ask if i want to allow windows to make changes, but nothing happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu8T6.png)

This is my Windows Defender registry:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender]
"DisableAntiSpyware"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Policy Manager]
"DisableAntiSpyware"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection]
"DisableBehaviorMonitoring"=dword:00000000
"DisableOnAccessProtection"=dword:00000000
"DisableScanOnRealtimeEnable"=dword:00000000

Will be grateful if you could help me

Comment: Tried to get the Windows Defender folder in the registry from another computer that has control over windows defender but it is still not working

Comment: Why do you need to disable Windows Defender? It works perfectly well. If you have a competent 3rd party Anti Virus competitor installed, it will automatically disable the real-time component of Defender. Otherwise let it run.

Comment: I want to install some mods for GTA. They are safe, i have them in another pc.

Also it was me that set windows defender this way in the past. On my other pc i can turn it off, here i can't

Comment: You can whitelist apps in Defender if you need to. The other machine may be a corporate machine or newer version of Windows.

Comment: I tried to whitelist the process, but it won't let me

Comment: I wonder if your registry settings have done some damage to the OS.  I have software (Cain and Abel) that WD really dislikes and I just whitelist it on both my machines.

Comment: I download a program to scan and search for errors then i corrected them. Still not working. How can i know if my os is damaged?

Comment: Undoing registry changes is very difficult to do truly properly. You may need to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: Yeah this is what i was fearing, i did every tutorial on youtube blogs sites but nothing worked

Comment: As of version 2004 W10 you cannot disable Defender via the registry anymore, see my answer for doing it for version 2004>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/947873/disable-windows-defender-in-windows-10/1590934#1590934

Answer (score 1):

Registry changes are usually dangerous unless done by a competent program or a skilled expert.

At this point, because changes have been made and cannot be returned to normal, back up your system and then reinstall Windows.

Preferably use the Manufacturer’s Recovery USB if you can. Otherwise be sure to update all drivers when you reinstall.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for all the help

Comment: You are welcome and hopefully you will acknowledge the answer I posted for you and others in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Powershell command to turn off/on the Windows firewall:

Please click "Start" and enter "PowerShell" --> open "PowerShell" and enter the following command --> then press the "Enter" key to run the command and the firewall will turn off.

**Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled False**

Turn on firewall by run the following PowerShell command:

**Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled True**

Display the current status of the firewall can also be achieved through PowerShell:

**Get-NetFirewallProfile -all | select -Property name,enabled**