# Is there no Microsoft-aproved way to disable Windows Defender in Windows 20H2?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

In short, I do not want "MsMpEng.exe" to be running in the background. I have tried the Group Policy method, but when I rebooted, that setting was set back to "Not configured". I have tried the Registry method, but HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\DisableAntiSpyware was automatically deleted after reboot.

Do Microsoft actively preventing such methods, and do not allow any method to disable it at all? I think I could try more dramatic methods like trying to delete the Windows Defender directory after booting into Safe Mode, but if possible, I want a cleaner method.

---

PS: In the TaskManager, I right-clicked "MsMpEng.exe", and then chose "Open file location". I opened the file's properties, and in the Security -> Advanced, I changed the file's owner from TrustedInstaller to my account. Then I removed all inherited permissions and made my own account the only account that can access the file. I rebooted the OS, and Windows Defender failed to start automatically, because it could not execute "MsMpEng.exe". I went up to its parent directories, and delete all of the Defender's directories. It seems that Windows is starting/running fine after that.

Comment: No there is not any approved way to disable Defender in windows 10, here is the un-approved way>>>>https://superuser.com/a/1590934/40928

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep Windows Defender from doing much if you install a good brand of third party antivirus.

If you have no other antivirus installed, then Windows Defender will run and cannot be disabled.

Those are the only two approaches with Windows 10 20H2 and also in upcoming Insider versions.

Answer (score 0):

You may turn all the options to Off in:
*Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection >
Manage settings*.

This will disable most of Windows Defender.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [winaero tweaker](https://winaero.com/) to disable windows defender on Windows 10 20H2

Comment: Is this a Microsoft-approved way?