# How can I prevent Windows Defender from using my computer's CPU on Microsoft Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, windows-defender

I use Microsoft Windows 10.  I don't want to use Windows Defender. Therefore I disabled it, but it continues to use my computer's CPU. How can I prevent that?

---

Here's how I tried to disabled Windows Defender:

[image]

But Windows Defender continues to use my computer's CPU.

[image]
[image]

How can I prevent Windows Defender from using my computer's CPU on Microsoft Windows 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use Microsoft Windows 10. I don't want to use Windows Defender.
> Therefore I disabled it, but it continues to use my computer's CPU.
> How can I prevent that?

If you do not want Windows Defender real time scanning, install a good third party Anti Virus that will disable WD Real Time scanning.

About WD using CPU:   Properly set up Windows Defender (with no competing AV installed) does not use any appreciable CPU more than 90% of the time. It will do a quick scan on start up and then only scan new incoming files.

3 machines here with only Windows Defender and CPU is under 5% more than 95% of the time on all of them. You need to make sure your computer is properly set up.

Without a good third party AV, Windows Defender will always have real time scanning running, but at very low CPU. Without a third party AV, WD cannot be disabled.

Comment: Thanks, so no way to completely turn off Windows Defender?

Comment: Not any way to turn it off completely, no.

Comment: Yes there is, but you have to remove it>>>>https://superuser.com/a/1590934/40928

Comment: Newer Windows updates will normally restart Defender if turned off from all that I have read.