# Cannot edit registry Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-11, regedit

I always disable Windows defender on my machines via the registry editor, but this time I have run into a problem: first of all, I happen to have a Home version of Windows 11, so I had to install the registry editor manually, then when I try editing the value, it comes up with the following error:
[image: error1]

I have read about this, and everybody states that I have to run regedit as administrator (which I do) and give myself permissions over the "Windows defender" folder. When editing permissions I get the following error:
[image]

Keep in mind that I am using the Admin account, which is the only account in the system. After doing a little more research, I have found that you should be able to change the owneer of the file, but in my case this is a dead end:
[image]
[image]

Is there any solution to that?

Comment: did you try to disable it via the GUI or via GPO (not sure if the latter is possible in the home edition)?

Comment: "I had to install the registry editor manually" - The registry editor exists on every edition and version of Windows.  So what exactly have you installed? The only thing I know for certain is that it wasn't the registry editor.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe not the editor itself, but something that supports it. When I first tried opening it, my PC didn't know what is "regedit", and there was nothing in the search as well. Maybe it was because I installed one of the earlier builds of Windows 11, idk.

Comment: So what exactly did you enable because your theory of it due to being an insider preview build is also incorrect. Every relevant version of Windows has had the registry editor.

Comment: @Ramhound After some time I have remembered that I have install the group policy editor, not the registry. I don't get why you make such a big deal out of this, it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @user9102437 - Sometimes details matter.  I don't understand the reason you are upset with somebody simply trying to understand any changes you have made to your system in order to potentially help answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry if it came out rude, I ganuanly didn't understand the relevance. Hope it is clear now :)

Comment: @user9102437 - The relevance does not matter, perhaps, it was just a matter of "details matter" and I was trying to educate you on the fact the registry editor is in every version of Windows (since originally thought otherwise).  [This](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy) open source project was suggested in the past [here](https://superuser.com/questions/947873/) have you tried the generated script that disables Defender? Obvious warning: Using the registery, to disable Windows Defender is dangerous, but it's the only way to do so. The script should work for Windows 11.

Comment: I should add disabling Windows Defender forcefully, will likely introduce strange behavior, since it wasn't meant to be disabled. in order to disable it, you have to disable relevant services and features, which you might notice due to strange behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound No, I havan't tried using any tools, but I have edited the group policies suggested by your link. I will read into it, thank you for the suggestion and a warning the well.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 11 Home, Windows Defender is enforced and that is why you cannot disable it via the registry (by Microsoft Design).

If you wish, you can get a very good 3rd party Anti Virus and installing that will put Windows Defender in the background. That suffices for most uses.

Comment: Unless you're creating a honeypot to see how quickly your PC can be subverted... ;-)

Comment: That is a real pitty if it is truly impossible :(. Installing the other antivirus is not a good option, because the whole idea is to get rid of useless apps, which do noting except load up your cpu and memmory occasionally.

Comment: Windows Defender is a top notch AV app, not useless at all.

Comment: @John That is true, but for me any antivirus software is just an annoying resource eater, since with enough caution there is generally no threat of getting a virus.

Comment: It would be foolish not to have any AV.  My CPU runs at <5% more than 95% of the time (all machines) so no resource issue.