# windows 11 family antimalware service executable cannot been kill

Tags: windows-11, anti-virus, windows-defender

Before you judge me saying there is already answer, I want to tell you that didn't work on windows 11. I has tried a lot of ways to kill it but it's still using more than 30% cpu of 12 core which is a lot. I'm pretty worried about it because I think it's not normal for a antimalware use so many cpu. When i trying to kill it in task manager it just denied access(I'm the administrator of the computer). I wish there is like some command like "sudo kill id -9" in linux.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1054257/how-do-i-kill-antimalware-service-executable this does not work for me, when I trying to edit the value, it says failed to change the value

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Comments are meant for clarification etc. to add details to your question [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1784778/edit) and add them there.

Comment: As @YisroelTech states, copy the name of the application you want to stop into the question. There is no "Windows 11 family antimalware" application or process, unless that is the name of **malware** with which your PC is infected.

Comment: so it's a virus?

Comment: if it is a virus How do i kill it?

Comment: How do I add picture to my command?

Comment: plus I'm talking about "antimalware serivce executebale" instaed of "Windows 11 family antimalware"

Comment: You [edit the question](https://superuser.com/posts/1784778/edit) adding/clarifying the details. To add a picture (while editing) click the image icon from the editor toolbar.

Comment: thank you, I just added new photo for process name and file name

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to be able to **kill** an antimalware program (there are commands like `sudo kill` but they will encounter the same errors.) If it'd be so easy then all malware would do that... Antimalware solutions have built-in protections to prevent that.

If you want to ***Turn Off*** Windows Defender Antimalware you'd need to do it from the settings.

(I do not think that there is such a thing as a "*Windows 11 family antimalware*", if you have more details on its location and filename maybe we could tell what it is.)

Comment: Thank you, I has just added the file and process name of the thing

Comment: @james okay, that Windows Defender. Did you try turning it off from the settings (at least temporarily) to see if the CPU usage goes down?